# Update app store available

Tags: iphone, ipad, app-store

I have a question. I can say when I want show my update in the app store? or when I send update can't select the moment for show my update?

If I put a new available date my app dissapear in the app store?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

When you create a new version of an already released app on iTunes Connect, you are asked to chose between having the update being released automatically after being approved, or releasing it later yourself manually.

In any case, the previous version will remain available on the App Store until the new version is released.

Comment: If you release an update yourself manually after it is approved, the previous version remains in the store unchanged (unless you manually remove that version or something).

Comment: So just to confirm, if I send the app to Apple for approval and say I want to release it manually it will just sit there until I say otherwise. I want to do a little bit of last minute testing although I'm 99.9% sure that the app is ok, this means I can get it approved and if my tests are ok release it later on.